# Cannot add an image to my custom webhook

Tags: office365connectors

Any reason why I can't click the upload image button when trying to customize my webhook? Is this a known bug or just something on my end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a intermittent bug, as it is working for Microsoft Edge 25.10586.0.0 and Chrome 48.0.2564.116

If you share your browser version and repro details via email at connectorbugs@service.microsoft.com, we'll track this down. Thanks for helping us catch issues during our developer preview!

Comment: The issue was you have to be the creator of a webhook in order to change the image, and I was not the creator. I suggest though that you make this obvious is some way. Thanks though!